Relationship error on Laravel Filament store
I'm trying to make a relationship on Laravel Filament from Products table and Items table, i created product table, items table and a intermediate table to store what product has a what items, i make the relationship between tables products to itemProducts and itemProducts to items but  i had this error
enter image description here
thie is my Product Model
enter image description here
this is my itemproduct model
enter image description here
and this is my items model
enter image description here
I tried change a form to do relationship and change to belongstomany, and tried make relationship direct on the items table to product table, but i have the same error

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
